# What does command `settings.action.editFocusedSetting` do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I've tried this command in the settings UI/JSON split editor, but it doesn't seem to do anything, does anyone know the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to figure this out. It is basically a relic from before the days of the new Settings UI. It has no function in the Settings UI but if you have these settings:

```
"workbench.settings.editor": "json",
"workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true
```

you will get back the older method of editing settings and there `settings.action.editFocusedSetting` has a function. In the demo, I search for a setting `mouseWheel` and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> through the search results. You will see on the right in User Settings it will find those settings if I had previously made a change.

Then triggering `settings.action.editFocusedSetting` opens the options for changing the setting in User Settings and one of those can be selected.

If there was previously no setting to match the focused setting in the left-hand search results, it will offer to create one in User Settings.

[image: edit focused setting demo]

So as I say, not sure this is used anymore by many people. But it does work nicely if you don't like the newer Settings UI.